# "The cats drinks its milk" or "Cats drinks their milk"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, possessives

> "The cats drinks its milk"
>
> "Cats drinks their milk"?

I don't if these sentences are grammarly correct. I  have to use "its", "their", or both?

Answer (score 1):

Since "cats" is a plural word you must use a plural pronoun: "their"

But you must also make the verb correct. You have the wrong form of the verb. What is the correct form? Fill in the blank

> One cat drinks milk.
>   Two cats ..... milk.

The word "The" changes the meaning, but both with and without "the" could be correct.